# Rewrite MySQL code to retrieve average time

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I don't know if that's a question for SO, if not please delete it. I am using the query below to calculate an average time it takes for a ticket on our service desk to get closed.

I don't have write permissions on the database, so I can't create functions, variables etc.

I strongly believe that there must be a better/nicer, more robust way to calculate that, than my query below, any thoughts?

What I want to avoid, if possible, is to recalculate the count value, which especially with all the where clauses makes the query a bit slow.

```
SELECT Count(hd_ticket.id)                                AS 'Tickets #', 
       ROUND(( Timestampdiff(hour, hd_ticket.created, hd_ticket.time_closed) / 
                     (SELECT Count(hd_ticket.id) 
                     FROM 
                       hd_ticket 
                       LEFT JOIN hd_status 
                              ON hd_status_id = hd_status.id 
                     WHERE 
                     Month( 
                       hd_ticket.time_closed) = 12 
                     AND 
                     Year 
                       (hd_ticket.time_closed) = 2017 
                     AND 
                       hd_status.state LIKE '%close%' 
                     AND 
                       hd_ticket.hd_queue_id IN ( 8 )) )) AS 
       'AVG Closure Time' 
FROM   hd_ticket 
       LEFT JOIN hd_status 
              ON hd_status_id = hd_status.id 
WHERE  Month(hd_ticket.time_closed) = 12 
       AND Year(hd_ticket.time_closed) = 2017 
       AND hd_status.state LIKE '%close%' 
       AND hd_ticket.hd_queue_id IN ( 8 )
```

In a nutshell what the above query does is

```
SELECT COUNT(TICKETS) as 'Tickets #',
ROUND(TOTAL_TIME_TAKES_TO_CLOSE_TICKETS/COUNT(TICKETS + FILTERS)) as 'AVG Closure Time'
    FROM HD_TICKET
    SOME FILTERS
```

Comment: Move `AND hd_status.state LIKE '%close%' ` from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result.

Comment: could you use CTE? The whole expression (`Select count(hd_ticket...`) is just a static number. Please refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html
So basically you would just use `WITH numberoftickets AS (SELECT Count(hd_ticket.id) etc.)`

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for your comment and tip, I can't see how I can do that? Could you write it down for me? I think I am missing something

Comment: @RobertStettler I will give it a go thanks :)

Comment: @RobertStettler I think I don't have permissions to use WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT Count(*) as Num_Tickets_Closed,
       AVG( ( Timestampdiff(hour, t.created, t.time_closed) ) as AVG_CLosure_Time
FROM hd_ticket t LEFT JOIN
       hd_status s
       ON t.hd_status_id = s.id 
WHERE t.time_closed >= '2017-12-01' AND
      t.time_closed < '2018-01-01' AND
      s.state LIKE '%close%' AND
      t.hd_queue_id IN ( 8 ) ;
```

Notes:

- First, you can just use `AVG()`.  That greatly simplifies the query.
- The date comparisons are made without functions.  Although this likely has little impact in your case, it allows the use of indexes.
- The names of the columns no longer have special characters, so they don't need to be escaped.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your reply. While your query is simpler, the avg function does not return the same result, if I remove the AVG function just to check the timestampdiff value it is the same as my query. Therefore something in the AVG function skews the results.

Comment: @Sonamor . . . That could happen if `created` or `time_closed` were `NULL`.  That latter is not possible, because of the `where` clause.

Comment: Created and Time_Closed do not allow NULL values